# How to remove diacritics in Perl 6

Tags: raku

Two related questions.
Perl 6 is so smart that it understands a grapheme as one character, whether it is one Unicode symbol (like `ä`, `U+00E4`) or two and more combined symbols (like `p̄` and `ḏ̣`). This little code

```perl6
my @symb;
@symb.push("ä");
@symb.push("p" ~ 0x304.chr); # "p̄" 
@symb.push("ḏ" ~ 0x323.chr); # "ḏ̣"
say "$_ has {$_.chars} character" for @symb;
```

gives the following output:

```perl6
ä has 1 character
p̄ has 1 character
ḏ̣ has 1 character
```

But sometimes I would like to be able to do the following.
1) Remove diacritics from `ä`. So I need some method like

```perl6
"ä".mymethod → "a"
```

2) Split "combined" symbols into parts, i.e. split `p̄` into `p` and `Combining Macron U+0304`. E.g. something like the following in `bash`:

```perl6
$ echo p̄ | grep . -o | wc -l
2
```

Comment: Would `"ä".samemark('a')` work for you?

Comment: It works, thank you! Though I'm not sure that I understand the documentation for `.samemark` method

Comment: `"your string".samemark('c')` goes through each character in your string and applies the mark of `'c'` (which is none) to it. This basically is the same as saying that each character in your string needs to have the same encoding mark/diacritic as the string you pass into `samemark`.

Comment: What a wonderful utility!! As I see, if needed, it adds both combining and non-combining diacritics. `> "abc".samemark('ā')` gives `āb̄c̄`, where ā is one unicode symbol and `b̄` is two.

Comment: The reason `b̄` is two Unicode codepoints is there is no precomposed codepoint for that combination. Unicode would have to be about `[*] 1..300` times bigger to account for all the possible combinations of base characters and combining codepoints.

Comment: @BradGilbert, yes of course I understand it. The question is what is the best way to split (if needed) such characters, consisting of two and more Unicode codepoints.

Comment: @BradGilbert, in my answer to callyalater's comment I didn't mean to complain that `b̄` consists of 2 symbols. It was rather a praise of the `.samemark()` method on my side. :)

Comment: It just seemed as if you didn't understand how Unicode operates, so I was trying to clear any misunderstanding up.

Comment: @BradGilbert Gilbert Anyway thanks, my knowledge is very insufficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perl 6 has great Unicode processing support in the `Str` class. To do what you are asking in (1), you can use the [`samemark`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Str#routine_samemark) method/routine.

Per the documentation:

> ```
> multi sub samemark(Str:D $string, Str:D $pattern --> Str:D)
> method    samemark(Str:D: Str:D $pattern --> Str:D)
> ```
>
> Returns a copy of `$string` with the mark/accent information for each character changed such that it matches the mark/accent of the corresponding character in `$pattern`. If `$string` is longer than `$pattern`, the remaining characters in `$string` receive the same mark/accent as the last character in `$pattern`. If `$pattern` is empty no changes will be made.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> say 'åäö'.samemark('aäo');                        # OUTPUT: «aäo␤» 
> say 'åäö'.samemark('a');                          # OUTPUT: «aao␤» 
>
> say samemark('Pêrl', 'a');                        # OUTPUT: «Perl␤» 
> say samemark('aöä', '');                          # OUTPUT: «aöä␤»
> ```

This can be used both to remove marks/diacritics from letters, as well as to add them.

For (2), there are a few ways to do this (TIMTOWTDI). If you want a list of all the codepoints in a string, you can use the [`ords`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Str#method_ords) method to get a `List` (technically a `Positional`) of all the codepoints in the string.

```
say "p̄".ords;                  # OUTPUT: «(112 772)␤»
```

You can use the [`uniname`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Str#(Cool)_method_uniname) method/routine to get the Unicode name for a codepoint:

```
.uniname.say for "p̄".ords;     # OUTPUT: «LATIN SMALL LETTER P␤COMBINING MACRON␤»
```

or just use the [`uninames`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/uninames#(Cool)_method_uninames) method/routine:

```
.say for "p̄".uninames;         # OUTPUT: «LATIN SMALL LETTER P␤COMBINING MACRON␤»
```

If you just want the number of codepoints in the string, you can use [`codes`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Str#(Cool)_routine_codes):

```
say "p̄".codes;                 # OUTPUT: «2␤»
```

This is different than [`chars`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Str#(Cool)_routine_chars), which just counts the number of characters in the string:

```
say "p̄".chars;                 # OUTPUT: «1␤»
```

Also see @hobbs' answer using `NFD`.

Comment: Combined with @hobbs' answer that's a perfect solution to my problem.

Answer (score 4):

This is the best I was able to come up with from the docs — there might be a simpler way, but I'm not sure.

```
my $in = "Él está un pingüino";
my $stripped = Uni.new($in.NFD.grep: { !uniprop($_, 'Grapheme_Extend') }).Str;
say $stripped; # El esta un pinguino
```

The `.NFD` method converts the string to normalization form D (decomposed), which separates graphemes out into base codepoints and combining codepoints whenever possible. The grep then returns a list of only those codepoints that don't have the "Grapheme_Extend" property, i.e. it removes the combining codepoints. the `Uni.new(...).Str` then assembles those codepoints back into a string.

You can also put these pieces together to answer your second question; e.g.:

```
$in.NFD.map: { Uni.new($_).Str }
```

will return a list of 1-character strings, each with a single decomposed codepoint, or

```
$in.NFD.map(&uniname).join("\n")
```

will make a nice little unicode debugger.

Comment: Thank you, it really solves both problems! Yet I wonder, whether there is a simpler solution...

Comment: What about [`samemark`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Str#routine_samemark)?

Comment: @hobbs Will do. Tell me what you think of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I can't say this is better or faster, but I strip diacritics in this way:

```perl
my $s = "åäö";
say $s.comb.map({.NFD[0].chr}).join; # output: "aao"
```

Comment: There are now combiners that come before a base char, which would break this code.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, Brad. It works nicely at least for Portuguese and Ancient Greek, though.