# s/// and combined diacritics in Perl 6

Tags: raku

Another side of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46798994/how-to-remove-diacritics-in-perl-6?noredirect=1#comment80546307_46798994) problem. 
When I try to substitute a part of a combined character, Perl 6 by default wouldn't split it.

```perl6
my $p_macron = "p" ~ 0x0304.chr; 
say $p_macron; # "p̄" 
(my $a_macron = $p_macron) ~~ s/p/a/;
say $a_macron; # OOPS, again "p̄"
```

How to (temporarily) switch off this default, to be able to match a single Unicode symbol, not a combined one?
Here is how it is done in `bash`.

```bash
$ echo p̄ | sed 's/p/a/'
ā
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sed` doesn't work on Unicode codepoints, it works on bytes so when it is given `p̄` it sees `0x<0070 0304>` whereas Perl 6 properly sees it as one grapheme, and treats it as such. Which means `s/p/a/` would do absolutely nothing as `p` doesn't match `p̄`.

You could have tried `s:ignoremark/p/a/` (`:m`) which would have given you `a`,
or `s:samemark/p/a/` (`:mm`) which would have given you `ā`

Comment: What do `(:m)` and `(:mm)` mean? Should I put them after the `s///`?

Comment: Ah, I see, it's just another way of writing the adverbs.